# dokku/dokker can not access to local host

Tags: docker, iptables, dokku

I am using Dokku (and not an expert in Docker).

Everything works fine, except that I can not access to one of my web service from the docker container: a time out is generated. 
   The exact same code works fine from a different machine, accessing to the remote host.

I suspect things related to docker routing, but not sure exactly what to check. I see nothing related to docker or docku in the iptables?

Comment: guys downgrading without explanation is always a pleasure! A comment to explain why it's a bad question/problem would be better

Answer (score 0):

Enter in your docker container with

`docker exec xxx`

or nsenter if you have a docker version < 1.3
https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

and check with traceroute, ping, mtr, netstat and others the connectivity (maybe you will have to install them)

Here is the doc for docker exec

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec

Comment: This is not a solution to the OP's problem. Rather, it's a tip to diagnose the problem.